# Delete file from Pull Request on GitHub

Tags: git, github, pull-request

I have make pull request on git (with "xcodeproj/project.pbxproj" file - my fault), so can I delete this file from created Pull Request? Thanks..

Comment: Since July 2018, this is easily done from the Web UI of GitHub: see [my answer below](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755303/6309).

Answer (score 23, accepted):

- Make a commit that deletes this file and push it.
- Go to your fork's Github page and click *Pull Request* again. You will get a message stating that you already have a pull request, and that you can adjust the commit range for it.
- Include your new commit (with the deletion).

The offending file will still be in the changesets to be merged, mind you, so if it contains sensitive data it's best to close the pull request and wipe out the file from your fork's repository first. Github help [describes](http://help.github.com/remove-sensitive-data/) how to do that.

Comment: I would prefers @nulltoken solution because Xion one leaves the error visible in the history. It's not like if you were correcting a bug and you want to keep track of it. You submitted a file by error, so it should be removed from history, even if it does not contain sensitive data.

Comment: i removed the file manually and now `git rm` says pathspec doesn't exist. So git rm isn't working, git status shows no changes

Comment: A slight variation worked for me in BitBucket. Shorter steps. Thanks!
- Make a commit that deletes this file and push it.
- Go to your BitBucket repo
- Verify file removed from lastest commit
- Click go to Pull Request. 
- Verify the file is removed.

Answer (score 42):

You probably will merge this pull request on master,
so you can checkout just this specific file again, from master,
on your branch, just type:

```
git checkout master -- xcodeproj/project.pbxproj
git commit -m "removing a file from PR"
git push origin {YOUR BRANCH}
```

Comment: How does committing a message remove the file from a PR?

Comment: @dougKimzey pretty sure the first line says "use masters version of xcodeproj"

Comment: It should be noted that the first line isn't getting origin's version of master. You may need to checkout master and pull beforehand.

Answer (score 27):

Another solution would be to

- Locally **rewrite** your commit(s) by removing the file, using **amend** or **rebase** git features
- **Force push** your branch toward your GitHub repository

This will update the pull request by only displaying your refreshed commit(s).

Comment: This solution is better because the history is clean. The deleted file will not appear anymore : the mistake will not be visible at all.

Comment: It would be good to update this answer to include example commands

Comment: An example would be good.  Git can be extremely confusing because it tends to use vague terminology when describing ambiguous commands.

Answer (score 5):

[New approach](https://blog.github.com/changelog/2018-07-31-removing-files-from-a-pull-request/), since July 2018:

> ### Removing files from a pull request
>
> Previously, if you wanted to use GitHub to remove files from a pull request, you’d need to switch to the pull request branch and look for the individual file to delete it.
>
> Now, if you have write permission, **you can click on the ‘trash’ icon for a file right in the pull request’s “Files changed” view to make a commit and remove it**.

**Warning**: as confirmed by [RCM](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4595768/rcm) in [the comments](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9498201/delete-file-from-pull-request-on-github/51755303#comment111211061_51755303):

**It does delete the file**.

> It DOES NOT mean it will remove your changes to the file.
> It is quite deceptively worded, in my opinion.

Comment: If the file existed before the changeset you are viewing, does this delete the entire file or only the changes to the file that happened that changeset?

Comment: @Luk From what I understand, it deleted the entire file and make a new commit recording that deletion.

Comment: Yes, I want to come in late and belabor this point, because it's important.  Because YES, EXACTLY, it means it will delete the file.  It DOES NOT mean it will remove your changes to the file.  It is quite deceptively worded, in my opinion.  More than this, shouldn't there really be a way to achieve what OP is asking for?  Sure, you can revert commits, cherry-pick commits, etc., but sometimes it would be nice to target one file.  it should be possible.

Comment: @RCM I agree and have included the warning in the answer.

Answer (score 5):

To remove a file from your PR:

```
git rm path/toFile/youwantRemovedOffyour/PR
git commit -a
git push
```

To remove a directory from your PR:

```
git rm -r path/toFiles/youwantRemovedOffyour/PR
git commit -a
git push
```

Answer (score 2):

CAUSION : Will delete local file also. Suitable when you pushed an auto generated file.

```
git rm <path to file>
```

Answer (score 0):

If all you want to do is just remove(delete) the changeset of a file that is already a part of the pull request, currently you can't do that via the web UI. 
You have to update the file locally and do a git push to the PR.