# How to delete binary file from pull request on GitHub?

Tags: git, github, merge, pull-request

I received a pull request for my GitHub project. This pull request includes some unneeded files so I would like to delete them. It's a pretty straightforward procedure for text files:

- Go to pull request
- Switch to `Files changed` tab
- Click `...` and `Delete file`
- Commit the change

However, the `Delete file` option seems to be **unavailable for binary files**.

Is it a GitHub bug, GitHub web interface limitation or something? What is the proper way to delete a binary file from an incoming pull request?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I mentioned that [feature back in July 2018](https://stackoverflow.com/a/51755303/6309) (see [documentation](https://help.github.com/en/github/managing-files-in-a-repository/deleting-files)).

But if this is not working/available, simply leave a comment on the pull request, for the developer having pushed said pull request to [delete the file on their local cloned fork](https://stackoverflow.com/a/9498304/6309), and push a new commit to their pull request branch.
That will update the PR, which won't show that file anymore.